# How to install firefox addon mozrepl on Web hosting server

Tags: perl, firefox-addon, web-scraping, mozrepl, www-mechanize-firefox

I have perl script for scraping which uses **WWW::Mechanize::Firefox** and firefox addon **MozRepl**.

Now, i need to deploy it on a web hosting server. The problem is that the they don't provide any interface or UI terminal so that i can launch firefox and launch it from there .

Can anyone tell me a way to install MozRepl addon in Firefox from the shell or by any other means

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stevie G

Yes i have used TightVNC server/viewer to connect to server with GUI, and then installed the required modules using the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python tool used, [CFX](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/cfx-tool.html), to develop the SDK and addons to automate installing of addons. In the future, we'd like to be able to install addons with the Firefox binary command line flags